# hover link over a non-rectangular div

Tags: html, css

I have a non-rectangular div with both a hover attribute and url anchor, shaped as such:

[image]

I would like to have the div clickable to a url link while changing its background color when the mouse hovers within the confines of the border.

What I currently have results in a clickable div outside of the borders around the bottom-right white space. Is there a way to "crop" the space out?

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.reddit.com" target="_blank" style="display:block">
    <div id="wai">
        <div id="ax" class="a"> </div>
        <div id="ex" class="a"> </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#ax {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#ex {
  width: 100px;
  height: 27px;
  background: blue;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -2px
}

#wai:hover .a{
  background:yellow;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyvBwa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't with your current HTML code because what you cannot see is that the surrounding `a` element shape is rectangular, this is what you are hovering on not the two inner `div`'s, to see it on screen add this to your CSS:

```
a { border:2px red solid; }
```

and you will see this result [**JSFiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ke8gbqqz/) which will show you the area of the outer `<a>`

```css
a {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
#ax {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#ex {
  width: 100px;
  height: 27px;
  background: blue;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -2px
}
#wai:hover .a {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.reddit.com" target="_blank" style="display:block">
  <div id="wai">
    <div id="ax" class="a"></div>
    <div id="ex" class="a"></div>

  </div>
</a>
```

to work around this, change the both inner `div`'s to `<a>`'s and with javascript change the color of both of them whenever you `mouseover` one of them, and set them back to the original color when the `mouseout` as in this [**JSFiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8b9qqp3n/1/)

```js
var links = $('#wai a');
links.on('mouseover', function() {
  links.css({
    'background-color': 'yellow'
  });
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  links.css({
    'background-color': 'blue'
  });
});
```

```css
#ax {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#ex {
  width: 100px;
  height: 27px;
  background: blue;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -2px
}
#wai:hover .a {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wai">
  <a id="ax" href="http://www.reddit.com" target="_blank" style="display:block"></a>
  <a id="ex" href="http://www.reddit.com" target="_blank" style="display:block"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the outer `div` `#wai` to `display:inline;`, and change second `div` `#ex` to `display:inline-block;`.

```css
#ax {
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
border: 2px solid black;
}
#wai{
display: inline;
}
#ex {
width: 100px;
height: 27px;
background: blue;
border-left: 2px solid black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
border-right: 2px solid black;
margin-top: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover #ax, a:hover #ex{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.reddit.com" target="_blank">
<div id="wai">
<div id="ax" class="a"> </div>
<div id="ex" class="a"> </div>
 
  </div></a>
```

Comment: While this nicely smartly the bottom `div` problem, the upper `div` still has the same issue as it even if you're not actually over the blue it will act like it is hovered because acting like a block, setting it to `inline` or `inline-block` won't fix it because the bottom `div will rank up next to it and not below it as wanted in the OP

Comment: As shown in this image, http://prntscr.com/8xzji9 even though the red area is outside the shape the hover effect will be triggered if you mouse over it